# Why is my react native view behind the top navigation bar on Android using Expo Go?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

When running my React Native application on Android in the Expo Go app, I've noticed recently that my view is getting hidden behind the top navigation bar. It wasn't like this before. The view is rendered under the top navbar on iOS - as expected - but it doesn't on Android. I can't seem to figure out what's going on here. I will share the screen's code below. See the screenshot for an example of the issue.

**Version Info**

```
"expo": "~47.0.11",
"react-native": "0.70.8",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
```

**SearchStackScreen.jsx**

```
const SearchStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function SearchStackScreen() {
  Bugsnag.setContext('SearchStackScreen');

  const languageStore = useSelector(selectLanguageStore);
  const isDarkTheme = useTheme().dark;

  return (
    <SearchStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: isDarkTheme ? colors.dark : colors.off_white
        }
      }}
    >
      <SearchStack.Screen
        name={TabBarStackScreenNames.search}
        component={SearchScreen}
        options={{
          headerLeft: () => <DefaultHeaderLeft />,
          headerShadowVisible: false,
          title: ''
        }}
      />
      <SearchStack.Screen
        name={MainStackScreenNames.search_profile}
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerBackTitle: languageStore.back,
          headerRight: () => (
            <ProfileHeaderRight
              user={route.params.user}
              currentUser={route.params.currentUser}
              isCurrentUsersProfile={route.params.isCurrentUsersProfile}
            />
          ),
          title: route.params.title
        })}
      />
    </SearchStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**SearchScreen.jsx**

```
function SearchScreen({ navigation }) {
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    main: {
      flex: 1
    },
    no_users_text: {
      flex: 1,
      paddingVertical: sizes.sm,
      textAlign: 'center'
    },
    placeholder_container: {
      flex: 1,
      paddingHorizontal: sizes.md,
      paddingVertical: sizes.sm
    },
    results_container: {
      flex: 1
    },
    search_bar: {
      backgroundColor: isDarkTheme ? colors.dark : colors.off_white,
      borderRadius: 0
    },
    search_gif: {
      height: 200,
      marginBottom: -20
    }
  });

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.main_screen_container}>
      {!currentUserInfo.verified ? (
        <CTAScreen
          body={languageStore.searching_disabled_message}
          buttonText={languageStore.get_verified}
          handleAction={() =>
            navigation.navigate(TabBarScreenNames.settings, {
              screen: MainStackScreenNames.settings_verify_identity_overview
            })
          }
          image={SearchGif}
          imageStyle={styles.search_gif}
          title={languageStore.searching_disabled_title}
        />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.main}>
          <Searchbar
            iconColor={isDarkTheme && colors.white}
            inputStyle={globalStyles.text_regular}
            onChangeText={(text) => handleSearch(false, text)}
            onSubmitEditing={() => handleSearch(true, searchQuery)}
            placeholder={languageStore.search_for_villagers}
            placeholderTextColor={isDarkTheme ? colors.grey : colors.grey}
            selectionColor={colors.primary_light}
            style={styles.search_bar}
            value={searchQuery}
          />

          {loading ? (
            <View style={styles.placeholder_container}>
              <ListOfUsersPlaceholder twoLines={true} />
            </View>
          ) : (
            <View style={styles.results_container}>
              {noUsersFoundText ? (
                <Text
                  onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
                  style={[globalStyles.text_regular, styles.no_users_text]}
                  suppressHighlighting
                  variant="bodyLarge"
                >
                  {noUsersFoundText}
                </Text>
              ) : (
                <FlatList
                  data={usersToList}
                  keyExtractor={(_, index) => index}
                  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <UserListItem
                      displayLocation={true}
                      enlargePicture={true}
                      handlePictureAction={() =>
                        goToProfileScreen(
                          languageStore,
                          navigation,
                          item,
                          currentUserInfo,
                          true
                        )
                      }
                      index={index}
                      makeEverythingTouchable={true}
                      user={item}
                    />
                  )}
                  ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
                    <View style={globalStyles.divider_thin} />
                  )}
                />
              )}
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Screenshot of Issue**

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded expo to version 48 and all the dependencies based on this blog post by Expo: https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-48-ccb8302e231. This resolved my issue! It doesn't seem right that just upgrading some versions of packages would fix the problem, but I'm glad that did the trick.